# Is there different in size of image when we get same using imageWithContentsOfFile and imageNamed

Tags: ios, iphone

I am drawing images on PDF, but when i get images using **imageWithContentsOfFile** to draw on PDF then PDF size is 133.6 mb  but when i get same images using **imageNamed** to draw on PDF then PDF size is 568 KB. I am unable to understand why this differece occure?

```
    static int i = 0;
NSString *path = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
NSString *filePath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.pdf", ++i]];
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(filePath, CGRectZero, nil);
for (int pageCounts = 1; pageCounts <= 15; pageCounts++) {
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, 2000, 1960), nil);
    for (int imageCount = 1; imageCount < 9; imageCount++) {
        NSString *newFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",imageCount] ofType:@"png"];
        CGRect rectFImage1 = CGRectMake(15, 400*imageCount, 700, 400);
        UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:newFilePath];


        [image1 drawInRect:rectFImage1];

        CGRect rectFImage2 = CGRectMake(800, 400*imageCount, 700, 400);
        UIImage *image2 = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:newFilePath];
        [image2 drawInRect:rectFImage2];
    }
}
UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();



    static int i = 0;
NSString *path = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
NSString *filePath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.pdf", ++i]];
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(filePath, CGRectZero, nil);
for (int pageCounts = 1; pageCounts <= 15; pageCounts++) {
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, 2000, 1960), nil);
    for (int imageCount = 1; imageCount < 9; imageCount++) {
        CGRect rectFImage3 = CGRectMake(315, 400*imageCount, 700, 400);
        UIImage *image3 = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png",imageCount]];
        [image3 drawInRect:rectFImage3];

        CGRect rectFImage4 = CGRectMake(1200, 400*imageCount, 700, 400);
        UIImage *image4 = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png",imageCount]];
        [image4 drawInRect:rectFImage4];        }
}
UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
```

Comment: With no other changes? Do you have multiple resolutions of the same images (using @2x)?

Comment: No, there's not. It's probably a question of when the image is getting inflated (uncompressed). For compressed images (JPG, PNG, etc.), the image may not be not inflated until iOS has to render it. I'd check the memory usage after you use it in your PDF, not immediately after loading it.

Comment: all images are captured using iphone 5 and having same resolution. drawing rect area is 700x400 for each image. i generated two pdf with same images with same drawing area. but both pdf's are different in size.